# Multiple listboxs bound to same function

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, widget

Honestly, I do not feel like this should be happening, but it is.

```
self.marketList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.market_selected)
self.jobsList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.job_selected)
```

There really isn't any more interaction between these two functions. When you click on an item in the marketList box, it's supposed to bring up the jobs in the jobsList box. Currently, it is applying the binding two both boxes. When I click on a job entry in the jobsBox, it clears the jobs and my troubleshooting is showing that it's calling market_selected. I'm not sure why this is happening, but it's really messing with what I'm trying to do with it.

How can I ensure that my binding is on only one widget, and won't be applied to multiple widgets?

edit:
I'm told that this isn't enough code to reproduce the error.

This is all the relevant code.

As I said previously, self.market_selected is called when I click on anything in the jobsList

edit #2
I uploaded the entire script.

```
import MarketWizard
import JobWizard
import SpanWalkerDocuments as swd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

import SpanWalkerDocuments as SpanWalker

class SpanWalker:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title('Luke Spanwalker')
        self.root.resizable(True, True)

        self.MainFrame = Frame(self.root, bg='red')
        self.sidebarFrame = Frame(self.root, bg='blue')

        self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self.sidebarFrame)

        self.marketFrame = Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.clientFrame = Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.jobsFrame = Frame(self.tabControl)

        self.polesFrame = Frame(self.MainFrame, height=100, width=50)

        self.tabControl.add(self.marketFrame, text="Markets")
        self.tabControl.add(self.jobsFrame, text="Jobs")
        self.tabControl.add(self.clientFrame, text="Clients")
        #self.tabControl.add(self.polesFrame, text="Poles")

        self.tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

        self.MainFrame.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.sidebarFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        #Awesome, our tabbed control is ready.

        #Now, we need to make the listBox widgets that will actually display our data.

        self.marketList = Listbox(self.marketFrame)
        self.jobsList = Listbox(self.jobsFrame)
        self.polesList = Listbox(self.polesFrame)

        #Binding functions! Yay for binding functions!

        self.marketList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.market_selected)
        self.jobsList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.job_selected)

        self.curMarket = ""

        self.markets = []
        self.jobs = []
        self.poles = []

    def UpdateMarkets (self):
        if len(self.markets) > 0:
            self.markets.clear()
            self.marketList.delete(0, END)

        for mark in swd.Market.objects:
            self.markets.append(mark)

        for m in range(0, len(self.markets)):
            self.marketList.insert(m, self.markets[m].title)

    def OpenMarketWizard(self):
        mw = MarketWizard.MarketWizard()
        mw.RunMarketWizard(self.root)

    def market_selected(self, event):
        print("Market Selected")
        selection = self.marketList.curselection()
        selectedMarket = ",".join([self.marketList.get(i) for i in selection])
        self.PopulateJobs(selectedMarket)

    def PopulateJobs(self, market):
        self.jobs.clear()
        self.jobsList.delete(0, END)
        self.GetJobs(market)

        for j in range(0, len(self.jobs)):
            self.jobsList.insert(j, self.jobs[j].jobName)    

    def GetJobs(self, market):
        marketJobs = []
        jobs = []
        if market =="":
            return 
        for j in swd.Job.objects:
            jobs.append(j)
            print("Market = {0}".format(market))

        for i in jobs:
            if i.market == market:
                self.jobs.append(i)
        
    def job_selected(self, event):
        print("Job Selected")
        selection = self.jobsList.curselection()

        selectedJob = ",".join([self.jobsList.get(i) for i in selection])
        print("The selected job is: {0}".format(selectedJob))


    def PopulateMarkets(self):
        self.marketList.destroy()

        for m in range(0, len(self.markets)):
            marketList.insert(m, self.markets[m].title)

    def OpenJobWizard(self):
        jw = JobWizard.JobWizard()
        jw.RunJobWizard(self.root)

        #We need to pack everything that belongs in our tabbed function.
    def marketListDisplay(self, show):
        if show == True:
            self.marketList.pack(fill="both")
            self.UpdateMarkets()
            self.newButton=Button(self.marketFrame, text="Open Market Wizard", command=lambda:self.OpenMarketWizard())
            self.newButton.pack()
            self.refreshButton=Button(self.marketFrame, text="Refresh Markets", command=lambda:self.UpdateMarkets())
            self.refreshButton.pack()
        else:
            self.marketList.forget_pack()

    def jobsListDisplay(self, show):
        if show==True:
            self.jobsList.pack()
            self.newButton = Button(self.jobsFrame, text="Create New Job / Open Job Wizard", command=lambda:self.OpenJobWizard())
            self.newButton.pack()
        else:
            self.jobsList.forget_pack()

    def polesListDisplay(self, show):
        if show==True:
            self.polesList.pack()
        else:
            self.polesList.forget_pack()

        #Query, why not put them all in a function?
sp = SpanWalker()
sp.marketListDisplay(True)
sp.polesListDisplay(True)
sp.jobsListDisplay(True)
```

Comment: Well, you are telling us that there is no further interaction, and you don't show us enough code to reproduce the error, so what are we supposed to say, exactly?

Comment: Fair. Edited with more code. This is all the relevant code related to the listboxes that I'm using.

Comment: presumably this is part of a class as it refers to `self`, but i don't see the class anywhere ?

Comment: We need just enough code to reproduce the problem on our machines. Please see [mcve].

Comment: Try adding `exportselection=0` when creating the two listboxes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was given by acw1668. I just added exportselection=0 during the creation process for the listboxes, and it worked perfectly.

Sorry for the confusion, y'all, I've never really asked for help on here before.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: there's no need to answer you own question:) especially when your issue is solved by other's comment.

Comment: I just wanted to ensure that anyone having a similar issue knew that that was the solution, but I'll keep that in mind in the future, thanks!